# Edit Knex insert to take array of parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, knex.js

I have this `Knex` update:

```
NoteTag.createNoteTag = async (noteId, tagId, db) => (
    db.sequelize.knex('note_tags')
      .returning([
        'id',
        'note_id',
        'tag_id',
      ])
      .insert({
        note_id: noteId,
        tag_id: tagId,
      })
  );
```

I'd like to be able to pass `tagId` as an array so that multiple tags could be added to a note.

Can I edit the function to do this and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knex's insert supports an array of object as well, so you can iterate over passed tagIds and map them to the insert object.

```
NoteTag.createNoteTag = async (noteId, tagIds, db) =>
  db.sequelize
    .knex('note_tags')
    .returning(['id', 'note_id', 'tag_id'])
    .insert(tagIds.map(tagId => ({ node_id: nodeId, tag_id: tagId })));
```

Comment: thanks. Rather than hard coding the `insert` values I assume I can include some function inside the `insert` to loop through the `tagId` array and include any found in the insert.

Comment: Correct, checkout my updated code, I'm mapping over tagIds

Comment: Actually, if I pass in more than 1 tagId e.g. `[1, 3]` both get added correctly to the database but only the first is returned.

Comment: Correct, if your DB is MYSQL, this is a DB limitation, not Knex's